Averaging the results after applying STFT-transform with overlapping windows
I always wondered if there is any "averaging" method for STFT with overlapping windows. I couldn't find much information about it in papers or literature.
I will try to explain what I mean by averaging. Take, for example, a simple sinusoid defined over some finite time interval. Let's analyze this sinusoid by applying STFT with overlapping windows. To make it simple, let's just break the time interval into two windows that overlap somehow. For each window separately we are plotting the spectrogram that will give us a single peak on the sinusoids' frequency (maybe distorted a little by side lobes, it depends on the window function). Then we try to assemble it all into a global spectrogramm by summing all the results with respect to time. When summing on the time interval where windows overlap, the amplitudes will be doubled giving us the wrong peak.
I know that for a simple sinusoid there is no need to use STFT, but I was trying to explain what happens to the individual harmonics which managed to get at the intersection of windows.
Is it possible to average the results and make the global spectrogramm "correct"? I know that simply didiving by $2$ is not always the case, because the harmonic could be presented with different time duration in each window.
Any help is appreciated.

You can average magnitude or magnitude-squared, if you want.  You can also average the complex spectrum of adjacent STFT spectra if you're careful to make the correct phase adjustment to the spectra from different times.  This spells out the math for how to keep these windows phase aligned.

Turns out, Dan Boschen, one of our key contributors on this forum gave an excellent workshop on this very topic just yesterday at the DSP Online Conference https://www.dsponlineconference.com/ . There are still some cool talks today if you are interested
What you are describing is basically Welch's method which is readily available in Matlab, Python, etc. As Dan describes in his workshop: For high precision estimates the tricky bit here is to ensure that the overlapping windows by themselves add to unity. Most existing implementations use a Hanning window with 50% overlap which does exactly that. Other windows may require different overlaps.

Thanks for your help! I've been using built-in Python methods for STFT and "smothing" the results but wanted to know the math behind it. My own investigations
haven't taken me far because I was lacking key words for search. You directed me to the right place. I've just read a few articles and it all became clear to me. Thank you once again!
